# Feelin' a misfire but ain't showng no misfire in the computer

Tags: ford, obd-ii, misfire, econoline

I swears when I turn on my van just sitting there I feel a misfire more often than any good person should.  In my opinion, I shouldn't be feeling any weird shakin or nothin.

When she's been driven a while... and I stop at a light for a short time, she purrs like a kitten... but when I first turn her on... even if it's after a short stop... sum ain't right.

I usually got a gallon of water sittin close by and I can sees it ripplin with my own eyes so I knows I ain't crazy.

Hooked up one of them fancy new bluetooth odb2 sockets and connected to my phone.  paid extra for the ford diagnostics but when I look at the misfire count it dont show nothin - zero.  no trouble codes.

Well I lied... during a drive, I've show a max 1 total misfire - one. And one time it was on cylinder 5... and the other time it musta been cylinder 7 or 8 because my diagnostics only goes up to cylinder 6 (which I think is kinda suspect).

As far as the conditions where it happens, I only feel it when the rpm s about 1200 or less and she idles down to 600.

It does seem to be related to whether or not the engine has load on it cuz it happens in park but not in drive... or not even when in park with the AC turned on.

Am I feelin a misfire or not?

If it ain't a misfire then what the heyl is it?

Comment: What RPM is that Tachometer showing when engine is both running rough and smooth?

Comment: Thas a good question I'll look into it... but that still don't answer why a misfire would not be counted by the computer... or what could feel like a misfire and not actually be a misfire.

Comment: Maybe the idle it too low which makes it feel like a misfire.

Comment: She idles anywhere from 700-900 or even 1200.... but usually settles to 800.  But she does that goofy stutter anywhere in that range... usually when I stop to make a phone call.  Why an am I even sayin this? it's irrrelevant.  Imma put a bounty on this as soon as I get my stripes.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to say that I appreciate y'all.  Y'all good people round here.  Ya hear me?

Comment: What in the heyl?  Come on y'all.  Don't one mechanic in the whole wide world want fiddy points?

Answer (score -1):

Well, there could be a number of things wrong, but here are three possibilities. If your fuel filter is dirty, the engine will hesitate or misfire upon startup. Also, if the belt slips on the alternator pulley on startup, it may not be able to give the spark plugs enough power to ignite the fuel in some of the cylinders. Later, the belt will heat up and grip the alternator better. Lastly, the timing in your distributor could be off, causing one cylinder to misfire, but that's not likely considering that it goes away later. Hope it helps!  :)